# Google login says error creating password: invalid_grant

Tags: android, download, google-authentication

When i try to open up the site http://android.googlesource.com/ to get android source code, 
Google says I have to generate new password, which is strange since I can access other sites without no problem with my Google account.

Anyway, I allow sending my account to http://android.googlesource.com/ and then it says either I have to revoke my PW and regenerate PW or put machine android.googlesource.com login git-y.jaeyong.gmail.com password ***************** into my `~/.netrc`

I tried both things but not working.

I have no idea what is going on.

So my question is "is there anybody who had similar problem?" or beside this problem, "is there anyone who tell me the git address to android honeycomb?"

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instruction on http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Answer (score 0):

I generated a password in `https://android.googlesource.com/new-password` and I overwrote `~/.netrc` with:

> machine android.googlesource.com login git-[your_email].gmail.com password 1/naIKPrD4.......
>   machine android-review.googlesource.com login git-[your_email].gmail.com password 1/naIKPrD4.....

It worked for me.